# Adding tag to select2 before ajax search is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently my select2 works with the ajax request, I can retrieve the data just fine from the php file.

now what I am trying to accomplish is:

- Allow a user to add a tag before the ajax request is done.
- Stop the request if a tag is added.

The reason why I need to allow a user to add a tag before the ajax is done. Is for the fact that the ajax can take some time (searching a lot of data)

below is the contents of the options of my select2. I am working with vue2 and the select2 has been made its own component and we pass in the options.

```
tags: true,
width: '100%',
multiple: false,
maximumSelectionSize: 1,
ajax: {
    url: this.$webRoute('ajaxController'),
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
        };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
        var mappedData = _.map(data, function(o){
                var text = o.member_number + ' - ' + o.first + ' ' + o.last + ' (' + o.st_number + ' ' + o.st_predir + ' ' + o.street + ' ' + o.st_type + ' ' + o.st_dir + ' ' + o.unit + ' ' + o.section + ' ' + o.city + ' ' + o.state + ' ' + o.zip5 +')';
                return {id: o.member_number, text: text};
        })

        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
            results: mappedData,
            pagination: {
                more: (params.page * 30) < mappedData.total_count
            }
        };
    },
    cache: true
},
minimumInputLength: 3,
```

Comment: And why is `php`-tag here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking to be able to add a tag before the ajax is done this is the solution I wrote. uppon entering the transport method, it fires a success, thus returning the tags. It will fire another success even when the axios is, it will then append the results to the list of options

```
tags: true,
width: '100%',
multiple: false,
createTag: function (params) {
    return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term,
        newTag: true
    }
},
insertTag: function (data, tag) {
    data.push(tag);
},
ajax: {
    delay: 250,
    transport: function (params, success, failure) {

        success([""]);

        if (params.data.term !== undefined) {
            axios({
                url: vm.$webRoute('ajaxController'),
                responseType: 'json',
                method: 'post',
                timeout: 1000,
                data: {
                    q: params.data.term
                }
            }).then(function(response){
                if (response == -1) {
                    failure();
                }else{
                    success(response);
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                failure();
            });
        }
    },

    processResults: function (data) {
        var mappedData = [{}];
        if (data[0].data !== undefined) {
            var mappedData = _.map(data[0].data, function(o){
                //process data
                return {id: o.member_number, text: text};
            })
        }else if(data[0].id !== undefined){
            mappedData.push({id: data[0].id, text: data[0].text});
        }

        return {
            results: mappedData,
            pagination: {
                more: false
            }
        };
    }
},
maximumSelectionSize: 1,
```